# Как реализовать личные сообщения и чаты в Django

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Я изучаю Django и столкнулась с такой проблемой: в гайде по созданию концепции личных сообщений и чатов я встретилась с не поддерживаемым куском кода из старых версий. В документации нашла лишь отчет об удалении такого генератора, но не написано, чем заменить такую штуку.

Итак вопрос заключается в том, как заменить `@models.permalink` в описании моделей чата:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class Chat(models.Model):
    DIALOG = 'D'
    CHAT = 'C'
    CHAT_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (DIALOG, _('Dialog')),
        (CHAT, _('Chat'))
    )

    type = models.CharField(
        _('Тип'),
        max_length=1,
        choices=CHAT_TYPE_CHOICES,
        default=DIALOG
    )
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, verbose_name=_("Участник"))

    @models.permalink      # Что делать с этим куском кода?
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return 'users:messages', (), {'chat_id': self.pk }
```

Comment: Просто удалить. Зачем его заменять на что-то?

Comment: @andreymal То есть функционал это не изменит? Ведь этот декоратор связывает юрл модели с вьюхой, которая должна отображать ее

Comment: Этот декоратор ничего ни с чем не связывает, он просто конструирует ссылку из указанных параметров. Чтобы сконструировать её самостоятельно, нужно импортировать функцию `from django.urls import reverse` и внутри метода get_absolute_url написать что-то вроде `return reverse('users:messages', kwargs={'chat_id': self.pk})`